# Is the maximum of $\sum\limits_{\mathrm{cyc}} \frac{1}{3a + 5b + 7c}$ equal to $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{5}$?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

> Let $a,b,c>0$ such $ab+bc+ac=1$. Show that
> $$\dfrac{1}{3a+5b+7c}+\dfrac{1}{3b+5c+7a}+\dfrac{1}{3c+5a+7b}\le\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{5}.$$
> (*Note*: $\mathrm{LHS} = \mathrm{RHS}$ when $a = b = c = 1/\sqrt 3$.)

since dear Mac sir,he solve [with inequality $\frac{1}{3a+5b+7c}+\frac{1}{3b+5c+7a}+\frac{1}{3c+5a+7b}\le\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1318792/with-inequality-frac13a5b7c-frac13b5c7a-frac13c5a7b-le-fra?rq=1)

use same methods,I think
$$(3a+5b+7c)^2\ge 75=75(ab+bc+ac)?$$
I would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: We can prove this inequality by the $uvw$'s technique.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way, though not very elementary.  The inequality is cyclic and on clearing denominators, will be of degree $3$.  By the "CD3-improved" theorem on [page 315 of Pham Kim Hung's book](http://gil.ro/downloadable/download/sample/sample_id/1/), the inequality will hold iff

1. it holds for $a=b=c$ and
2. if it holds when $c=0$.

For the 1st condition,  $\displaystyle a=b=c \implies \frac3{15a} \ge \frac{\sqrt3}5 \implies a \le \tfrac1{\sqrt3}$
which is true as the constraint ensures $a^2 = \frac13$.

Similarly for the 2nd condition, $c=0 \implies b = 1/a$ and we need to show
$$\frac1{3a+5b}+\frac1{3b+7a}+\frac1{5a+7b} \le \frac{\sqrt3}5$$
which can be after some jugglery shown equivalent to
$$105 \left(a-\tfrac{71}{42 \sqrt3}\right)^2 a^4+\tfrac{74839}{252} \left(a-\tfrac{35700 \sqrt3}{74839}\right)^2 a^2+\tfrac{20376025}{74839} \left(a-\tfrac{1421941}{1630082 \sqrt3}\right)^2+\tfrac{1036164125}{9780492} \ge 0$$

---

P.S. Will see if a more satisfying way is possible, or perhaps someone will come up with one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Lagrange multipliers. Let's denote
$$L(a, b, c) = \frac{1}{3a+5b+7c} + \frac{1}{3b+5c+7a} + \frac{1}{3c+5a+7b}-\lambda(ab+ac+bc-1);$$
we have system
$$\left\{\frac{\partial L}{\partial a}=0, \frac{\partial L}{\partial b}=0, \frac{\partial L}{\partial c}=0\right\},$$
or
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
\frac{3}{(3a+5b+7c)^2} + \frac{7}{(3b+5c+7a)^2} + \frac{5}{(3c+5a+7b)^2}+\lambda(b+c)=0\\
\frac{5}{(3a+5b+7c)^2} + \frac{3}{(3b+5c+7a)^2} + \frac{7}{(3c+5a+7b)^2}+\lambda(a+c)=0\\
\frac{7}{(3a+5b+7c)^2} + \frac{5}{(3b+5c+7a)^2} + \frac{3}{(3c+5a+7b)^2}+\lambda(b+c)=0
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
It's linear system for squares in denominators; solution is
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
\frac{1}{(3a+5b+7c)^2}=\frac{90}{\lambda}(11c-4b-19a)\\
\frac{1}{(3b+5c+7a)^2}=\frac{90}{\lambda}(11a-4c-19b)\\
\frac{1}{(3c+5a+7b)^2}=\frac{90}{\lambda}(11b-4a-19c)
\end{aligned}
\right.,
$$
or if you prefer
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
(3a+5b+7c)^2(11c-4b-19a)=\lambda/90\\
(3b+5c+7a)^2(11a-4c-19b)=\lambda/90\\
(3c+5a+7b)^2(11b-4a-19c)=\lambda/90
\end{aligned}
\right..
$$
We can solve this system in Maple, or to find solution in a form $a=b=c$:
$$
3c^2=1\Longrightarrow a=b=c=1/\sqrt3,
$$
and $\lambda = -243000c^3$ from the last system (other solutions are complex). Substituting it into your function, we have
$$
\frac{1}{3a+5b+7c} + \frac{1}{3b+5c+7a} + \frac{1}{3c+5a+7b}\le\frac{3}{15c}=\frac{\sqrt3}{5}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

**Fact 1**: If $x, y, z > 0$ with $-71(x^2 + y^2 + z^2) + 83(xy + yz + zx) = 2700$, then
$$\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y} + \frac{1}{z} \le \frac{\sqrt 3}{5}.$$
(The proof is given at the end.)

Now, let
\begin{align*}
 x &= 3a + 5b + 7c, \\
 y &= 3b + 5c + 7a, \\
 z &= 3c + 5a + 7b.
\end{align*}
We have $x, y, z > 0$ and
$$-71(x^2 + y^2 + z^2) + 83(xy + yz + zx)
= 2700(ab + bc + ca) = 2700.$$

By Fact 1, we have
$$\frac{1}{3a+5b+7c}+\frac{1}{3b+5c+7a}+\frac{1}{3c+5a+7b}
\le\frac{\sqrt{3}}{5}.$$

We are done.

$\phantom{2}$

---

*Proof of Fact 1*:

Letting $x = 5u\sqrt 3, y = 5v\sqrt 3, z = 5w \sqrt 3$, it suffices to prove the following:

**Fact 2**: If $u, v, w > 0$ with $-71(u^2 + v^2 + w^2) + 83(uv + vw + wu) = 36$, then
$$3uvw \ge uv + vw + wu.$$

Let $p = u + v + w, q = uv + vw + wu, r = uvw$.

The condition $-71(u^2 + v^2 + w^2) + 83(uv + vw + wu) = 36$
is written as $-71(p^2 - 2q) + 83q = 36$ or
$$q = \frac{36 + 71p^2}{225}. \tag{1}$$

Using $p^2 \ge 3q$ and (1), we have
$$p \ge 3.$$

It suffices to prove that
$$3r \ge q.$$

Using degree three Schur, we have
$$r \ge \frac{4pq - p^3}{9}.$$

It suffices to prove that
$$3 \cdot \frac{4pq - p^3}{9} \ge q$$
or (using (1))
$$\frac{1}{225}(p - 3)(59p^2 - 36p + 36) \ge 0$$
which is true.

We are done.