# Help me solve this inequality :$\forall x,y,z > 0 : \sum\limits_{cyc} \frac{x}{xz+2x+1} \leq \frac{3}{4}$

Tags: inequality, contest-math

I'm having trouble solving the following inequality problem:

Show that: $\forall$ $x,y,z > 0$ :
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{x}{xz+2x+1} \leq \frac{3}{4} $$
Here's my take :

First , i used the symmetry of the $LHS$ and assumed WLOG: $x\geq y \geq z$ .

Furthermore i get the three following inequalities based on our first assumption:

$xz+2x+1\geq z^2+2z+1 = (z+1)^2$

$xy+2y+1\geq z^2+2z+1 = (z+1)^2$

$zy+2z+1\geq z^2+2z+1 = (z+1)^2$

Therefore:

$$LHS \leq \frac{x+y+z}{(z+1)^2}$$

Now , From AM-GM we have :  $z+1 \geq 2\sqrt{z} \implies (z+1)^2 \geq 4z \implies \frac{1}{(z+1)^2} \leq \frac{1}{4z}$

And from  the assumption in the beginning :
$x+y+z \leq 3x$

Combining the two gives us :

$LHS \leq \frac{3}{4} \cdot \frac{x}{z}$

But then  since $x\geq z \hspace{2mm}$  i only get a really loose bound.

I've  made many more attemps on the problem but couldn't get anywhere.

I'd like to know where i've failed in my answer and know if there's an answer using well known inequalities (AM-GM , CS , Chebyshev , Jensen's ...).

Thanks in advance for any help given.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [with inequality $\frac{y}{xy+2y+1}+\frac{z}{yz+2z+1}+\frac{x}{zx+2x+1}\le\frac{3}{4}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1316870/with-inequality-fracyxy2y1-fraczyz2z1-fracxzx2x1-le-frac3) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum_%7Bcyc%7D%5Cfrac%7Bx%7D%7Bxz%2B2x%2B1%7D%5Cleq%5Cfrac%7B3%7D%7B4%7D%24&p=1).

Comment: FYI, there are also the AoPS threads [inequality-mathtodologist](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1305657p6976296) and [FCFPF ineq....](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h607889p3612856) (with your problem starting in message #$25$ of this thread).

Comment: Oh , my bad i was actually searching for this problem but couldn't find it for some reason , thank you for the info . I'm quite new  in mathstacks so i dont rly know how to look for for specific problems ... Have a nice day everyone and thanks again !